# Can’t identify object attribute: Uncaught ReferenceError: fat is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I’m building a simple application to calculate BMI as part of an JS exercise and can’t get past this error when I create an object to read inputs of my form. The error I get is the one in the title. Uncaught ReferenceError: `fat` is not defined at `HTMLButtonElement`.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#button-add");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form = document.querySelector("#add-form");
  var patient = getFormPatient

  console.log(patient);

  var patientTr = document.createElement("tr");
  var nameTd = document.createElement("td");
  var weightTd = document.createElement("td");
  var heightTd = document.createElement("td");
  var fatTd = document.createElement("td");
  var bmiTd = document.createElement("td");

  nameTd.textContent = name;
  weightTd.textContent = weight;
  heightTd.textContent = height;
  fatTd.textContent = fat;
  bmiTd.textContent = calculateBmi(weight, height);
  patientTr.appendChild(nameTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(weightTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(heightTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(fatTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(bmiTd);

  var table = document.querySelector("#patients-table");

  table.appendChild(patientTr);
})

function getFormPatient(form) {
  var patient = {
    name: form.name.value,
    weight: form.weight.value,
    fat: form.fat.value,
    height: form.height.value
  }

  return patient;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Queensland Nutrition</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <section class="container">
    <h2>My clients</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Weight(kg)</th>
          <th>Height(m)</th>
          <th>Fat Percentage (%)</th>
          <th>BMI</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="patients-table">
        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Paulo</td>
          <td class="info-weight">100</td>
          <td class="info-height">2.00</td>
          <td class="info-fat">10</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">João</td>
          <td class="info-weight">80</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.72</td>
          <td class="info-fat">40</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Erica</td>
          <td class="info-weight">54</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.64</td>
          <td class="info-fat">14</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Douglas</td>
          <td class="info-weight">85</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.73</td>
          <td class="info-fat">24</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Tatiana</td>
          <td class="info-weight">46</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.55</td>
          <td class="info-fat">19</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

  <section class="container">
    <h2 id="titulo-form">Add New Patient</h2>
    <form id="add-form">
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="nome">Name:</label>
        <input id="nome" name="name" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's name" class="campo">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="peso">Weight:</label>
        <input id="peso" name="weight" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's weight" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="altura">Height:</label>
        <input id="altura" name="height" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's height" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="gordura">Fat Percentage:</label>
        <input id="gordura" name="fat" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's fat percentage" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>

      <button id="button-add" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</main>

<script src="js/bmi-calc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I thought I might be making a mistake with variable names, but reviewed them and can’t find any. Any ideas on what I’m doing wrong here?

------------------------- EDIT ---------------------

adding code for the calculateBmi function to make it clearer. That's literally all the code I have for the exercise.

```
var patients = document.querySelectorAll(".patients");

function calculateBmi(weight, height) {
  var bmi = 0;
  bmi = weight / (height * height);
  return bmi.toFixed(2);
}

for (var i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {

    var patient = patients[i];

    var tdWeight = patient.querySelector(".info-weight");
    var weight = tdWeight.textContent;

    var tdHeight = patient.querySelector(".info-height");
    var height = tdHeight.textContent;

    var tdBmi = patient.querySelector(".info-bmi");

    var validWeight = true;
    var validHeight = true;

    if (weight <= 0 || weight >= 700) {
      validWeight = false;
      tdBmi.textContent = "Invalid weight";
      patient.classList.add("invalid-patient");
    }

    if (height <= 0 || height >= 3) {
      validHeight = false;
      tdBmi.textContent = "Invalid height";
      patient.classList.add("invalid-patient");
    }

    if (validHeight == true && validWeight == true) {
      var bmi = calculateBmi(weight, height);
      tdBmi.textContent = bmi;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, this line is probably the problem `fatTd.textContent = fat;` because you haven't declared `fat` anywhere.

Comment: The code you’ve posted throws the ReferenceError for `weight`. None of `weight`, `height` and `fat` are defined. What exactly are `nameTd.textContent = name;` and the similar three statements below it — for `weightTd`, `heightTd` and `fatTd` — supposed to do?

Comment: Literally the `fat` is not defined. You can define it by like `var fat = '123';` before using this variable. Don't forget doing same for `name`, `weight`, and the others.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys! The values for the attributes 'weight', 'height', 'fat', etc are supposed to come from the form inputs. So once I click the button I should be able to get the values and pass it to the table. I understand that this seems to be the problem as I was following a tutorial before and they're using code similar to mine (where it works just fine). I tried that before and now again, but if I use patient.field_name, it returns me no value. I'll add some code for the 'calculateBmi' function in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have no variables `name`, `weight`, `height`, or `fat`. I think you meant `patient.name`, etc.

But you didn't call the function in

```
var patient = getFormPatient
```

You need parentheses with the argument after it.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#button-add");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form = document.querySelector("#add-form");
  var patient = getFormPatient(form);

  console.log(patient);

  var patientTr = document.createElement("tr");
  var nameTd = document.createElement("td");
  var weightTd = document.createElement("td");
  var heightTd = document.createElement("td");
  var fatTd = document.createElement("td");
  var bmiTd = document.createElement("td");

  nameTd.textContent = patient.name;
  weightTd.textContent = patient.weight;
  heightTd.textContent = patient.height;
  fatTd.textContent = patient.fat;
  bmiTd.textContent = calculateBmi(patient.weight, patient.height);
  patientTr.appendChild(nameTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(weightTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(heightTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(fatTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(bmiTd);

  var table = document.querySelector("#patients-table");

  table.appendChild(patientTr);
})

function getFormPatient(form) {
  var patient = {
    name: form.name.value,
    weight: form.weight.value,
    fat: form.fat.value,
    height: form.height.value
  }

  return patient;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Queensland Nutrition</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <section class="container">
    <h2>My clients</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Weight(kg)</th>
          <th>Height(m)</th>
          <th>Fat Percentage (%)</th>
          <th>BMI</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="patients-table">
        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Paulo</td>
          <td class="info-weight">100</td>
          <td class="info-height">2.00</td>
          <td class="info-fat">10</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">João</td>
          <td class="info-weight">80</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.72</td>
          <td class="info-fat">40</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Erica</td>
          <td class="info-weight">54</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.64</td>
          <td class="info-fat">14</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Douglas</td>
          <td class="info-weight">85</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.73</td>
          <td class="info-fat">24</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="patients">
          <td class="info-name">Tatiana</td>
          <td class="info-weight">46</td>
          <td class="info-height">1.55</td>
          <td class="info-fat">19</td>
          <td class="info-bmi">0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

  <section class="container">
    <h2 id="titulo-form">Add New Patient</h2>
    <form id="add-form">
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="nome">Name:</label>
        <input id="nome" name="name" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's name" class="campo">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="peso">Weight:</label>
        <input id="peso" name="weight" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's weight" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="altura">Height:</label>
        <input id="altura" name="height" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's height" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="gordura">Fat Percentage:</label>
        <input id="gordura" name="fat" type="text" placeholder="enter patient's fat percentage" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>

      <button id="button-add" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</main>

<script src="js/bmi-calc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object patient has all the params,
so use patient.field_name to get the value.

```
var button = document.querySelector("#button-add");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var addForm = document.querySelector("#add-form");
  var patient = getFormPatient(addForm)

  console.log(patient);


  var patientTr = document.createElement("tr");
  var nameTd = document.createElement("td");
  var weightTd = document.createElement("td");
  var heightTd = document.createElement("td");
  var fatTd = document.createElement("td");
  var bmiTd = document.createElement("td");

  nameTd.textContent = patient.name;
  weightTd.textContent = patient.weight;
  heightTd.textContent = patient.height;
  fatTd.textContent = patient.fat;
  bmiTd.textContent = calculateBmi(weight, height);
  patientTr.appendChild(nameTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(weightTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(heightTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(fatTd);
  patientTr.appendChild(bmiTd);

  var table = document.querySelector("#patients-table");

  table.appendChild(patientTr);
})

function getFormPatient(form) {
  var patient = {
    name: form.name.value,
    weight: form.weight.value,
    fat: form.fat.value,
    height: form.height.value
  }
  console.log(patient);
  return patient;
}
```